# Create ssl certificate in aks and where to add it in manifest file of loadbalancer having kind service in AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have kubernetes service of type loadbalancer on azure cluster.that service must accept https req.How to create ssl cert and add them in annotations?

I read different articals but i am very confused between ingress , cert-manager and other things

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, service does not accept any annotations. So to use ssl/tls for your applications, ingress is the best choice. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls?tabs=azure-cli) is the official microsoft guide that will help through each step to setup ingress controller with LetsEncrypt cert-manager.

If you want to use your BYOC (bring your own certificates) from any known CA. Here are the steps.

Please follow the guide provided in above URL upto ***Use a dynamic IP address***.

```
kubectl --namespace ingress-basic get services -o wide -w nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller
    NAME                                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
    nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer   10.0.74.133   EXTERNAL_IP     80:32486/TCP,443:30953/TCP   44s   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
```

Create create secrets using .crt and .key file provided by CA. Assuming you are using default namespace for your application workload.

```
kubectl create secret tls TargetPods-tls --cert nameOfCertfile.crt --key privateKey.key --namespace default
```

Consume these secrets inside your ingress object and add annotations for http to https redirect

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true' # Annotation to redirect http to https.
  name: TargetPods-6dc98445c4-jr6pt
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.domain.io
    secretName: TargetPods-tls
  rules:
  - host: test.domain.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: TargetPod-6dc98445c4-jr6pt
            port:
              number: 80
```